# Graph a timer based on counts

Tags: graphite

I am sending timer metrics to Graphite and would like to create a graph of the counts based on the times buts I cannot do it or a line graph that is based on the value.
Tried playing with Graphite web app but no luck.

Example metrics
timer1 200
timer1 300
timer1 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to understand what you want.  Given the following data logged in [metric] [data] [timestamp] format

```
timer1 200 1s
timer1 300 50s
timer1 200 100s
```

(I know my timestamps are fake non-posix times, just trying to keep it simple)

Would you like to see something like

**(A)**
timer1's values summed by minute, so the (x, y) coordinates (0, 500) and (1, 200)

**(B)**
timer1's values summing up continuously over time like a counter, so the (x, y) coordinates (0, 200), (50,  500), (100, 700)

For **(A)**:

```
summarize(timer1, "1min")
```

For **(B)**:

```
integral(timer1)
```

You can apply functions to your data in the graphite webapp by putting the raw series data in a graph, then click Graph Data -> select your series -> Apply Function

Also read over the [documentation](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/functions.html) for different functions